# Is elongation a measure of plastic deformation?

Tags: materials

I did a tensile test of a metallic alloy, and I want to calculate it's elongation. Would it simply be the (failure strain - yield strain)?

For reference, I got the following values from the test:

Yield strain: 0.015
Yield stress: 404 MPa
Failure strain: 0.22
Failure stress: 592 MPa

Would the elongation simply be 0.22-0.015 = 0.205

0.205 * 100 = 20.5%? I.e. simply the amount of strain that was done plastically?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wishing luck to meet someone familiar with material science of engineering.

Comment: Literally, *elongation* means "how much *longer* is the piece". If you know its initial length, and length (total length of the pieces) after failure, that's sufficient to calculate elongation. I can't stress enough this calculation should be no strain at all.

Comment: How is this a chemistry question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I measured elongation and reduction of area on many bars, shapes, materials. Never calculated it, never heard on anyone calculating elongation. The elongation is the primary measure of ductility. The tensile machine graph puts out a strain  which is interesting , but we always measured the bars to be sure. That also give you a look at the fracture surface which can also be informative.  What are the units of your 0.015 strain; % ?, mm ? ( inches) of what gage length? Also various specifications have different definitions of yield.

Comment: "Mechanical Metallurgy" by  Dieter , McGraw  Hill; Is apparently in print after many decades. It has more than you want but must be worthwhile because it is still available.